# Is there a way to remove community wiki status?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-wiki, moderator-abilities

I accidentally checked the box on a question. Can this be undone?

Answer (score 67):

Yes—community moderators, *at their discretion*, can now remove community wiki status from particular posts.

Back when we had certain triggers to automatically convert certain posts into community wiki, this would also inoculate those specific posts from ever being auto-converted to community wiki again.

There are no more automatic conversions, but in the past, we felt the automatic "force community wiki" thresholds were correct:

- after 30 answers (15 on Super User and Programmers, [60 on Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/713)) are added to a question
- after a post is edited by more than 5 different users
- after a post is edited by the owner 10 distinct times

If you feel your post has been unfairly converted to community wiki and deserves treatment in lines with the new policy, you can flag it for moderator attention and plead your case to a community moderator.

Comment: Clarification: This says "inoculates... from ever being *auto-converted*", does this mean that either the author or a moderator can still *manually* convert it back to CW? And, if so, and I ask this purely out of curiosity, how does reputation work if votes accumulate while it is switching back and forth?

Comment: @aaro we don't really support converting back and forth, but when a moderator switches it permanently off, that mod should probably recalc rep on any affected users, too.. or it'll get picked up by the next global rep recalc once per year.

Comment: Force community wiki on *owner* edits is absolutely horrible.  It should die a swift death.  The only reason it exists is to prevent gaming by bumping, and that's a wretched excuse to so strongly discourage edits and improvements by the original author.  The problem is gaming - fixing it by penalizing edits and improvements is just insane.  Didn't anyone ask themselves why edits need to bump posts at all?  Why not just fix that broken behaviour rather than cripple one of the most useful tools (edit and improve) of SE sites?

Comment: @J... I wish I could upvote your comment a million times.

Comment: @J... I wish I could frame your comment and hang it on every wall of the SE offices.

Comment: The solution is to give the owner a grace period where any edits they make don't count against their limit of 10. I would recommend a day (12 hours on others if you choose). In that day if 5 others choose to edit as well (and preferably edit a certain amount) then it's still CW'd. After that day the owner will add to the edit limit.

Comment: The automatic triggers have been [removed as of April 2014](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/).

Comment: If I see someone elses question/answer being CW, should I comment to the OP or flag it myself?

Comment: @Default no point posting a comment. If for some reason you think it shouldn't be CW, flag it.