# How can I change my question back from a community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I mistakenly made my question on Stack Overflow into a community wiki. How can I change my question back from a community wiki?

> [Why am I not able to query a database from a forked child in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192707/why-am-i-not-able-to-query-a-database-from-a-forked-child-in-perl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It used to be that the only thing you can do is delete it and post it again as a new question.

However, as Sathya points out in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91420/59303) moderators have the ability to remove the CW status if they feel it is appropriate. So flag the question using the "other" option and explain your reasons.

Given that the original was down-voted (albeit without comment) you might want to take this opportunity to rework the question to see if you can improve it. However, this could lead to the question being closed as a duplicate - so take care with this option.

Unfortunately I don't know anything about Perl and DBI so I can't help you there.

Comment: It's likely to get closed as a duplicate. Some SMEs have a trigger finger for closing posts.

Answer (score 14):

(lot of removing CW on questions lead to here, so posting the answer).

Moderators now have the ability to remove community wiki.

Comment: Good to know.  Is it announced anywhere?

Comment: @CharlesStewart JeffAtwood mentions it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2974/133693)

Answer (score 1):

So you didn't get rep for it? Community wiki isn't going to keep you from getting help--at least I don't think the guys watching the Perl tag would only help you out only if there were rep involved.

Answer (score -2):

You can't. Not even moderators can set it back.

Comment: Thats problem .. Moderators has option to edit that ..

Comment: atleast they should have the options and i have tried rollback with old version also its not working .

Comment: Basically: You can't change it back because you don't 'own' the question anymore.

Comment: [This is no longer true.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10382/how-can-i-change-my-question-back-from-a-community-wiki/91420#91420)

Comment: Gladly! Because CW is a __reputation killer__. I kid you not: if you have a good answer that got you, say, 10 upvotes, and you edit it too often so it's turned CW, you will __no longer gain any rep__ on it! If you're rather rarely on-line on SO & Co., and you have only one good answer, this CW status can really cost you lots of rep loss - so be careful out there. Though "loss" does *not* mean you actually get your rep *subtracted*, it will no longer get you any additional rep *in future*. Yet one more reason why I hate this CW thing to the bottom of my heart - it's so pointless.