# Can a community wiki question be reverted back to non-wiki?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change my question back from a community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10382/how-can-i-change-my-question-back-from-a-community-wiki)

Can a community wiki question be reverted back to non-wiki?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10382/how-can-i-change-my-question-back-from-a-community-wiki

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not.  Not even moderators can do it.  I suppose the SO Team *could*, but I doubt they would.

Answer (score -1):

No, they can't.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256/allow-owner-to-un-community-wiki-a-question-or-answer) discusses non-wiki'ing as a feature request and the issues assosciate with that ability.

Answer (score -1):

Not even moderators can undo the community wiki status of a question or answer.

I would think that only one of the members of the dev team with access to the database could make that type of change and I imagine it happens very very infrequently (if at all).