# Can a question that was kicked to Wiki due to edits be reverted to non-Wiki status

Tags: support, specific-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change my question back from a community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10382/how-can-i-change-my-question-back-from-a-community-wiki)

This is about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852647/is-this-wpf-progressbar-odd-render-behaviour-a-bug).

I have only been a member of StackOverflow for a couple of days and was not aware that multiple edits of a question will kick a question into Community Wiki mode. I am now very mindful of the edit rules.

I was not trying to bend the rules -- I originally had problems getting the code posted, and this accounted for half of my edits. Others in the community also helped out, which I am grateful for.

It took time to write and was subsequently updated with good investigation on my part. (although ultimately others will be the judge of this.) As a result if the outcome of the question is founded it should enhance my reputation and more importantly be of benefit to the community.

StackOverFlow is a game changing resource which has helped me out many times and so now I want to try to give what I can back.

So this is a plea -  please be kinder to noobs trying to make a contribution.

Can the original question please be added reverted from Community Wiki mode?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10382/how-can-i-change-my-question-back-from-a-community-wiki.

Comment: While I agree it's a dupe, I think he's specifically requesting that his specific question get moved back -- although I'm pretty certain not even diamond mods can do that.

Comment: @Smurfsnorting 
I can asure you there is no deception intended what so ever on my part just noob ignorance - why would I use my name if that was part of my character.

I asked about the possibility of reasking it another way and was told that it was likely that I would be reported for abuse for trying to bump. I have to say I am not finding this a terribly friendly place at the moment.

Comment: Um, I think you may have misunderstood what I wrote -- the question is a duplicate ("dupe" is short for duplicate); I meant no ill will nor harm to you -- and in fact was trying to argue in favor of keeping this one open. I do mention that I don't think mods can do that, but again, I'm not attacking your character; I understand and empathize with your situation.

Comment: @Smurfsnorting - sorry for my misunderstanding (I am from the UK and thought it meant duping doh!) and thank you for your support.

Comment: No problem, it occurred to me when I read your response that there was a slight miscommunication there somewhere. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Community Wiki is a one-way switch; once it is on, it can't be removed.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - can I re-ask it a different way for the reasons I gave above without getting reported for abuse. If not I'll get over it and chalk it up as a lesson learned. 

On a different note:
Thanks for all you work on SO it really is a game changer and I applaud you sir.

Comment: you can delete your question and start over, if you like -- given the # of edits it seems it took a while to "get it right". I have no problem with that.

Comment: oh, and flag your question for mod attention if you need it deleted. Just use the "flag" menu option and explain what you want.

Comment: Thanks Jeff I appreciate your time on this. Ironically it had been partly answered and as it has now been fully answered so as not to complicate things further I will leave it as is. Fascinating mind food! Cheers