# How can I change my existing question to a community wiki?

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

How can I change my existing question to a community wiki?

I have a set of questions on Stack Exhcange sites. I wish to make them community wiki questions. Is there any option to change my question into a community wiki? I see there is an option to do so for answers. Why is there no such options for questions?

Comment: That sounds like you want to change many questions to a CW? Is that the case? Any particular reason to do so?

Comment: @Bart yup many for e.g http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/how-do-you-respond-when-a-child-catches-his-parents-having-sex this question,maybe my questions were hypothetical :(

Comment: That doesn't address the "why?". Why make them CW? What do you think that will do to your questions?

Comment: I don't think you grasp the concept of Community Wiki, that's likely the reason we can't do it ourselves anymore, as users marked without good reason.

Comment: Yeah, I fear this is going to end up in a set of inappropriate and therefore declined CW requests. (And I have a hunch you're trying to have your content disassociated from you, but only you can say if that's so).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can flag your questions for moderator attention and ask them to do it, but you would need a good reason for it.

Alternatively, edit your post more than 10 time and it will automatically be converted to CW. This is not welcome, as each edit will bump the question in the active list.

Other ways for posts to become CW automatically:

- Question with > 30 answers. Question and answers will become CW
- Post edited by 5 different people will become CW.

Comment: Side note: Unnecessary edits will push it in the active quesiotns queue which is unwelcome. And if I remember correctly it will not be converted instantly.

Comment: i have seen this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10382/how-can-i-change-my-question-back-from-a-community-wiki?rq=1 so this user made his question to community wiki by marking it to moderator?

Comment: @Lonelybaby Once upon a time users could mark their own question as CW.  That ability was removed some time ago.  That's an old question.

Comment: @Servy thanks for the update :)

Comment: Note for any new readers stumbling across this old Q&A: the automatic conversion of posts to community wiki due to too many edits, as described here, [was removed in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947). The only ways in which a question or an answer can now become a community wiki are described in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741).