# Is it true that once you mark a question as "Community wiki", you lose all points for it?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki

For example, if a question you ask get 20 up votes, so you probably get 100 points for it, but it seems like there are some questions out there that have 200 up votes but is a Community Wiki, and the user only have 200 rep points?

Once you change a question to community wiki, do you lose all points you got earlier, or for future up votes?

Comment: You should note that _questions_ can [only be turned CW by mods now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only future votes are affected; you still keep the reputation gains and losses from votes before entering CW

Comment: fyi we have a dev only feature that allows us to do this retroactively

Comment: Too lazy to update: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status