# Allow a moderator migration to strip off the community wiki flag

Tags: feature-request, migration

People have on occasion asked whether golf questions on SO should be migrated to Code Golf Stack Exchange. Notwithstanding whether this should or shouldn't be done, I think we should fix one big hurdle for doing such migrations:

**Golf questions on SO are community wiki. Golf questions on CGSE are not.** This pretty much renders most every golf question on SO unsuitable for migration to CGSE.

Obviously, only a moderator is able to migrate SO questions to CGSE. Should we add an option to the migration to enable the corresponding post on CGSE to *not* be CW?

Comment: Rep doesn't migrate anyway, regardless of CW status - so what's it matter?

Comment: @Shog9: It affects whether future answers get rep, as well as upvotes to current answers. This will decide whether the question is "live" or "dead", as far as whether people want to contribute further.

Comment: @Chris: Gotcha. FWIW, it's somewhat gratifying that you actually care, not just about *preserving* the SO questions, but actually turning them into *first-class-citizens* of the new site!

Comment: Do you want the old ones migrated?  I would think you'd just want the new ones migrated (which we can do without making them CW), and for the old ones to be re-asked on the new site so they get answered by the focused community of people interested in Code Golf.  That seems to be the general trend on new SE sites.  Let me know if CG is different.

Comment: "Golf questions on SO are community wiki" I thought we kicked all the code golf questions off SO already.

Comment: The problem is that this now makes the migrating site have to do some of the target site's moderation, which they're not really qualified to do. If there were a purgatory-like place between sites as has been suggested, this could work better.

Comment: Actually .. I think migration should always strip the community wiki status ...

Comment: @Shog9: As a pro-tem mod for CGSE, one could say that it's my job to care about this. :-)

Comment: @mmyers: Yes, a limbo-like place could work well too. But Robert Harvey has offered to migrate any questions we request, so if he doesn't mind doing the work, that's fine with me too.

Comment: @waffles: Yes, I agree, since it's easy for the target site's moderator to slap CW back on if they want to! But you work for SO, right? Surely you could make a strong case for this. ;-)

Comment: @Bill: I wouldn't want to migrate very many of the golf questions on SO; just (quality, or otherwise requested by users) ones that haven't really taken off, with the hope that with fresh eyes, they will really take off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Moderators are now able to remove Community Wiki status from questions that receive it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373). It's not automatic stripping, but this functionality mostly solves the unique problem that the puzzle site runs into with incoming code golf.

Comment: Indeed. Alas, it doesn't work, at least on CGSE. :-D (Too bad you don't have mod on that site. I put a mod-flag on one such post where this failed, asking the other mods to try it, and nobody can get it to work either.)

Comment: @Chris It's working for me on Gaming, so something is odd on Code Golf. How terribly unfortunate... I suggest posting a big bug report on your per-site-meta, then, highlighting this lack.