# Migrated CW question no longer community wiki?

Tags: support, migration, community-wiki

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62302/most-common-one-line-bugs-in-c#question) was migrated from SO to Programmers. It was marked community wiki on SO, but it looks like that's been cleared on Programmers.

I can't quite tell if the last answer was made before or after the migration, but at 43 answers the question should've been wikified automatically if a mod didn't explicitly convert it.

Did CW status get cleared in migration? If so, should it be or is that a bug?

Edit: the mod actions pop-up has the option to "Remove wiki" enabled and "Convert to wiki" is greyed out. This suggests to me that the post should still be CW, even though the question and answers don't say so.

Comment: I flagged it about a half hour ago to let them know it used to be CW. BTW, I think they actually made it so that questions lose their CW status upon migration.

Comment: @Gabe I'm one of the mods. Your flag is what made me wonder how it works now. :)

Comment: @Gabe [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81048/allow-a-moderator-migration-to-strip-off-the-community-wiki-flag/84800#84800) suggests CW is not automatically stripped, but it can be done manually by a mod.

Comment: It seems everything's CW now. Did anyone do anything?

Comment: @marcog I didn't touch it and I don't think any of the other mods did. I wonder if there was just a delay in displaying CW?

Comment: Could it have hit the auto-CW threshold while nobody was looking?

Comment: If it got any more answers it would have been made CW again.

Comment: Just a note - the question has now been deleted on **both** Stack Overflow and Programmers. It wasn't a good question (which is beside the point for the purposes of this question).

Comment: Here's [another example](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/68470) of such a question.  It was CW'ed back when the question was asked and apparently became un-CW'ed in the migration.  It appears that users that had existing accounts at the time of the migration will automatically earn reputation as if it was asked at the target site from the beginning (looking at GMan's [rep history](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/6503/gman?tab=reputation#reppage_2-repview_post)) and others who join afterwards don't appear to get this too.  Something looks very wrong about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct - community wiki is stripped during migration.  Normal rules on the destination site apply, so the question may get auto-converted to CW again - however these checks are done when a new answer is submitted.

Comment: Why aren't the checks done at migration time?

Answer (score 3):

The question eventually became community wiki. My best guess is that another answer came in that pushed the question over the auto-CW threshold on Programmers.

Community Wiki status is stripped during migration.