# I made my post as "community wiki" by mistake, can I restore it?

Tags: support, status-completed, community-wiki

Here: [Best way to store data for your game? (Images, maps, and such)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683582/best-way-to-store-data-for-your-game-images-maps-and-such/6683609#6683609)

Comment: No idea if even the moderators can do this. I highly doubt it.

Comment: @BoltClock A moderator can correct that.

Comment: @Anna Lear: Ah, I see it now. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373

Comment: I've sorted this for you.

Comment: Thanks @Kev I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A moderator can clear that for you. The best way to contact a moderator is to click the "flag" link on your answer and explain what happened.

The odds are pretty good that a Stack Overflow moderator will see this post, too, but flags are usually faster and more reliable, since your flag isn't going to get lost in a sea of general Stack Exchange-related meta posts.