# (Meta Only) Blacklist Request: feature

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta, retag-request, synonym-request

Based on the actual definition of [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) I believe that all questions tagged [request](/questions/tagged/request) should be reviewed (all (12?) of them), and a blacklist placed on the tag itself.  Some questions using the tag would be better with a feature-request tag, or without the tag altogether.  Request is being mis-used in place of feature-request and in place of retag-request / synonym-request in many questions.

I see that the [request](/questions/tagged/request) also exists on StackOverflow.SE, and that tag should stay as is (due to its usage for HTTP Requests, and anything to do with sockets (another issue, another question...))

This is not a straight of question, as I bet there is a better solution.  Hence: **discuss**.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think it should be removed. The first question in your example search is [I made my post as "community wiki" by mistake, can I restore it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98493/i-made-my-post-as-community-wiki-by-mistake-can-i-restore-it), and it is actually a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question. So maybe if it were blacklisted instead, things would work nicely. Given that you must include one of [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [support](/questions/tagged/support) they should be clear enough without the additional [request](/questions/tagged/request), which I agree is meaningless.

Comment: Alright.  I read your answer, and I like it a lot and you bring up good points.  So I've gone and modified my question to follow suite (as I agree this is a much better solution.)