# Cancel answered as community wiki

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to remove community wiki status?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status)

I have answered a question as community wiki. As I am not getting reputation for it, So I want to convert it to my answer. Is it possible to convert it back to my answer?

Comment: Why did you make it community wiki in the first place?

Comment: because I didnt know that votes will not affect my reputation..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention and specify that you want it un-wikified. At the same time you can do a reputation recalc, however I am not certain if you will gain reputation for the period that the answer was wikified.

However, in your case, your linked SO account is suspended and therefore you reputation has been set to 1. Until the suspension is lifted you will not be able to do anything on SO. You can see the reason for your suspension and for how long on your profile page on SO.

Comment: what if I dont have flag privilege?

Comment: @ACoder Everyone with at least 15 reputation can flag a post. Since you have got enough reputation on Programmers to get the association bonus, simply go into your profile on SO and re-associate your accounts. This should give you the association bonus of +100.

Comment: Yes I know. But my reputation is 13. So what to do?

Comment: @ACoder I updated my comment.

Comment: @ACoder Correction, it's seems you can't re-associate anymore. It's been a while since I checked the preferences. Also, you are aware your SO profile is currently suspended, which means you can't do anything until the suspension is lifted?

Comment: Rep Recalc is no longer an option after the recent rep changes AFAIK :)

Comment: @Rory Actually the option is still available for now. I used it yesterday. I often use it when I delete a post to rectify my reputation, since the system takes to long to update for my liking. Have a look at the reputation audit right at the bottom.

Comment: (@Diago, *officially* a recalc can [take up to 5 minutes for deletions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes). If you think it's much longer, then that might be a bug? Or, if 5 minutes is too long, then you'll like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127513/1-more-comment-when-you-submit-a-comment) `;-)`)