# "1 more comment" when you submit a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The “add / show x more comments” showing itself after posting a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126489/the-add-show-x-more-comments-showing-itself-after-posting-a-comment)

> Related: [Live notification shown for own edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130169/live-notification-shown-for-own-edits)

Minor bug-- Sometimes, when you submit a comment (and it is still in the `...` loading mode), the "show 1 more comment" box pops up. This box seems to refer to the comment you just typed. When the submission completes, this link disappears.

Repro steps:

- Write absurdly long comment.
- Submit it.
- Keep eyes peeled
- Wash. Rinse. Repeat.

As @Arjan mentioned, this is probably due to the realtime updates update. In which case its still a bug. And still insignificant :/

For some reason, I can't repro it on MSO in the comments of this post, but it does happen on Physics.SE. 0_O

Comment: That [newish realtime update](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) is lightning fast!

Comment: You may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to testYou may use this comment box to test