# Remove community wiki from my answer

Tags: support, status-completed, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to remove community wiki status?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status)

Can I turn my answer from this post [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression for .OrderBy function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428335/system-linq-expressions-expression-for-orderby-function/12436126#12436126) from community wiki back into a regular answer?

I didn't know what the wiki was until after I checked the box. If not, I don't care. It's just that it doesn't belong there I don't think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, just flag the answer as "other" and request moderator to convert it to normal answer.

See the flag link on your answer,

[image]

Click on it and choose option "other"

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lucifer.  How do I take an answer?  I tried to edit it, but I don't see any fields for tags.

Comment: Nevermind.  Figured it out.  You click on the "flag" link...duh

Comment: @FathomSavvy, no need to do it now, Anna(moderator) has already converted your answer to normal answer :)

Comment: Dear Mod, please remove the Community Wiki status answer and revert it back to a normal answer.

Answer (score 2):

I cleared community wiki flag from your post.

You're right, it wasn't needed on that answer. You can read more about the history and purpose  of CW [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).