# re-accepted answer does not reward +15 again?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, community-wiki, unaccepted-answer

Looks like OP miss clicked on the tick - any reason why the +15 isn't reinstated?

[image]

Comment: At least you now know what wiki is and how a post can be auto-wikied. Basically, try to keep your edits significant. And if possible try to "save" them up and do them all at once in one edit. Fortunately, this hit you on a not-so-upvoted post. But it has hit others the first time on +100s...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your answer became [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) before accepting it again.

Exactly what happen:

- Your answer was accepted on `2012-09-11` at that time it was not a community wiki answer so you got +15 for that.
- Then your post became community wiki post on `2012-09-21`.
- Then OP unaccept it (may be by mistake) so you lost 15 reputation.
- Then again OP accepted it. So you did not get 15 reputation as it is community wiki post.

Comment: Nice to be notified. This really makes me want to bother making my answers correct and updated. Guess that explains the lack of rep I've been getting across the board.

Comment: @Patrick That's one of the problems with auto-wiki. It's meant to prevent abuse by repeatedly bumping back to the front page. But at the same time, it also discourages edits.

Comment: Guess I'll have to stop being pedantic about my posts heh.

Comment: Can you rollback to say the first edit to reclaim an answer?

Comment: @Patrick did't get you.

Comment: Rolling back to a previous edit, does this constitute as an additional edit, or as the removal of existing edits - ie, can a rollback be performed to unwiki an answer?

Comment: @Patrick Yes. Rollback is also considered as edit. So you can not unwiki an answer like that. See [Is there a way to remove community wiki status?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status)

Comment: Thanks for the link : )

Comment: @hims056 I was able to reclaim my answer, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You have edited your answer more than 10 times ( which is [16 revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12316349/revisions) ), hence your answer become Community Wiki answer automatically.

As per the rule of the Community Wiki Answer, it doesn't generate any reputation, that's why you are not awarded +15 reputation again.

Comment: So, basically, don't bother keeping posts updated.

Comment: Why not, you should always make your post update ,if you found anything missing.

Comment: @Patrick if your answer is outstanding and multiple edits clearly indicate exemplary contribution, CW status can be removed from it - [see for example this meta discussion at Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/remove-cw-status-for-this-answer-hashing-algorithms-testing-by-ian-boyd)

Comment: @gnat, thanks - giving it a shot. If multiple edits lead to CW status, is it better to just c+p an answer to the new question and alter it slightly, rather than to edit an existing answer and point future answers to it?

Comment: @Patrick hards to say, this is [meta-tag:etiquette] matter. Copy-paste sounds somewhat slippery, community may dislike this tactics

Comment: @gnat so how do you get around the CW status when you find additional issues that relate and can improve your solution!

Comment: @Patrick I personally don't get around CW. As for the reputation, well I try to gain it in less slippery ways. It certainly pains when [only about 30 of 350+ upvotes](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/154741/31260 "an example") contribute to rep due to CW but I somehow learned to live with this