# Why my reputation doesn't increase on an answer I edited a lot

Tags: discussion, support

What wrong I did but don't know why my reputation doesn't increase after my answer is up-voted. This shows up-votes in my answer but couldn't be changed my reputation. Note to my reputation before up-vote and vote my answer to see my reputation is still as before.
[How does this CSS produce a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189208/how-does-this-css-produce-a-circle/16189854#16189854)

Comment: Your post got wikied from getting edited too many times.

Comment: Oh! editing too many times doesn't increase the reputation? What should I do to regain my reputation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That answer has been changed to a Community Wiki post because it was [edited too many times (note the revision comment)](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16189854/12), and you unfortunately won't gain any further reputation once a post becomes Community Wiki.

You could consider [flagging your answer and asking a moderator to remove Community Wiki status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83373/160551) (they may or may not actually do so, but it's worth a try if you feel all of your edits were legitimate).

See also: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: That means I couldn't edit my answer more than 10 times?

Comment: CW will trigger after ten of your edits.  It's intended to encourage people to be careful when editing and to avoid making trivial edits to bump their answer and gain free visibility.  For example, revisions 9-13 you were just changing a few characters, where if you had taken a little bit of extra time they could've been handled in the same edit.  Most of the other edits seem like substantial content edits, which is why I think you might be OK. It's a bit uncommon for one person to maintain an answer through so many edits, so this doesn't come up very often.

Comment: What is the full form of CW?

Comment: Hah! My reputation decreased after I flagged and user was removed. from 962 to 822

Comment: Anyway I'll be careful from now.

Comment: @Troyen- Hitting rep cap also cause this problem?

Comment: Hitting the rep cap would stop you from getting any more reputation for that day, but you would resume getting reputation from any new votes on the next day.  The rep cap is not involved with making a post Community Wiki.