# My answer was accepted, but I did not gain reputation from it. Why?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, accepted-answer, up-votes

After a lengthy period of editing in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032435/find-difference-between-two-fields-as-columns-in-a-table) and finally getting it right, the OP accepted my answer

> [image]

However, my activity list then showed the following entry:

> [image]

which is kind of disappointing. These are probably my hardest earned 0 points so far. ;-)

My votes activity list does not show any sign of my own voting on that post:

> [image]

Does anyone know what went wrong, or rather, what I did wrong?

Comment: Because it's a [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). You probably accidentally checked the checked box.

Comment: I have un-wikified the answer.

Comment: @JonW no, it's turned to CW automatically after 10 edits by the OP.

Answer (score 10):

Due to more than [10 times of editing by you](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18032621/revisions), the answer converted to [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). And you don't earn rep from CW posts.

Comment: Indeed. This is potentially an edge case, where someone who was trying to be helpful and add additional information to his answer in response to comments from the asker got bitten by the automatic wikification. [Moderators can un-wiki an answer that gets automatically converted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373); raise a flag to ask them to take a look.

Comment: Note for any new readers stumbling across this old Q&A: the automatic conversion of posts to community wiki due to too many edits, as described here, [was removed in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947). The only ways in which a question or an answer can now become a community wiki are described in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741).