# Allow "Remove Wiki" on a question to cascade down to answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, community-wiki

We recently had a question appear on the "Hot Network Questions" list, and it attracted a **lot** of attention to our site.

We are very grateful for the views, and the influx of new users (many of whom appear interested in sticking around, which is just fantastic for a beta site that needs more participants).

However, the question eventually automatically converted to wiki upon receiving 30 answers.

I'm not sure I see the point of it auto-converting after 30 answers, given how CW is currently supposed to be used (in the exceptionally rare case when it is appropriate).  At best it seems a poor alternative to protecting the question (which I don't think is necessary in this case).  At worst, it counters some of the benefit of the increased visibility we received, since new users probably don't want to come in to our site and participate by posting answers that won't receive reputation (it's even worse when they don't realize until after the fact that that is what happened).

That's not the point of this post, though.

The point is that I decided to remove the CW status from the question as soon as I noticed it.  Only to discover that I then had to manually go through 30 answers and repeat the process.

Can we have a feature that allows mods to remove CW status from a question **and** all answers in one shot?

Comment: That just seems like approaching a problem the wrong way. If it's made CW it should stay like that, and if it's not supposed to become CW, then I'd request for the feature to be removed entirely.

Comment: Another caveat - if that post gets _one_ more answer, you'll have to repeat the process all over again. This is something we're looking at currently.

Comment: @slhck It is acceptable for [moderators to remove CW status at their discretion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83373/166646).  Personally, I feel that 30 answers shouldn't auto-wiki, especially considering how the use of CW has changed, but that same answer states that they feel the 30 answer threshold is "correct".  Changes for CW have been rumored for a while, so that feature may very well be removed entirely, but until something happens, tools to help moderators use them the way they are intended would be appreciated.

Comment: @TimPost I thought manually removing wiki prevents further auto-conversion?  (see Jeff's answer linked in my comment above)

Comment: @Beofett, I think that's true of the *edit*-based auto-triggers (10 self edits, or 5 editors, but NOT of the answer-based auto trigger.   FWIW, we're looking hard at rolling back or changing a lot of the auto-triggers, largely because they have a very high false positive rate.

Comment: @Jaydles Please do! They are wrong so much more than right I basically reach for the mod remove tool on sight on both sites I mod. Only on meta have I seen it ever work right.

Comment: I have been in this situation before, IIRC I scripted the remove wiki bit :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been implemented and will be available shortly (build 3367 on MSE/MSO, build 2556 everywhere else).