# Why did I stop getting reputation for upvote - today's rep only at 95?

Tags: support

My total rep for the day is only 95, yet I didn't get any reputation points for an upvote on one of my answers.  Why?  Is there a limit on total upvotes per answer that will generate reputation?

[image]

The answer whose upvote didn't generate any additional reputation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript/7958422#7958422).  It is at a total upvote count of 106.

In doing research on this topic, I came across the 200 vote daily limit for upvotes (I'm way below that for today - though have hit it in the past) and a discussion about caps on total reputation for upvotes on a single answer which said there was no limit there.  So, I'm stumped.  Why did I not get any reputation points for today's upvote on the [Mimicking Sets in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript/7958422#7958422) answer?

Comment: Note for any new readers stumbling across this old question: the behavior described here [was removed in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947). It is no longer possible for questions or answers to get converted into community wiki due to too many edits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) post, and therefore no longer generates reputation for anyone. It was made community wiki automatically once you edited it a 10th time.

Comment: Interesting - that would certainly explain it.  Because I continued to improve my answer over time (12 edits all by myself), it was turned into a Community Wiki and thus I stop getting any further upvote credit.  Seems a bit odd.  I understand the other reasons for converting it to a Wiki, particular when lots of different people are editing it, but the fact that I continue to improve my answer means I now get no further credit for it.  Seems a bit of a reverse incentive.  Oh well.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I'll just put this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits . I went ahead and removed wiki status from that answer, since it sounded like you didn't want that.

Comment: @BradLarson - thx.  Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 3):

Your linked answer is marked Community Wiki, so it doesn't generate any reputation from upvotes, reputation cap or not.

According to the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7958422/revisions), you have edited 10 or more times, making it Community Wiki.

[image: Revision History Page]

Comment: The specific revision link http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7958422/11 shows the 'made Community Wiki by jfriend00 editing at least 10 times' in it clearly and might be a useful link.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers mention, it was made community wiki from you editing it 10 times.

In your case, the edits generally seem to be substantial, so you could try flagging the answer for moderator attention and asking them to [remove community wiki status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status) and then you can start getting reputation again from future upvotes.

Comment: Hmmm.  Maybe I should do that in this case.  Thx.  Your link has discussion about why the automatic conversion to wiki based purely on meaningful user edits does seem wrong.